# How do I use Python with apache2?

Tags: python, apache2

I'm trying to get Python working with Apache, however I'm failing to have success with either CGI or mod_python.

Does anyone know a good tutorial or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`mod_python` is basically non-maintained - you should look into `mod_wsgi`. Install the package `libapache2-mod-wsgi`, then issue `sudo a2enmod wsgi` to enable it.

Just as a quick example to get it running, stuff something like this in your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default`:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /test /path/to/python/file.py
```

And in the file `/path/to/python/file.py`:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return "Hello World"
```

After re-starting Apache2, any request to `/test` will turn into a call of `application()` in your python file.

For further reading, look into WSGI (WebServer Gateway Interface), *the* way Python integrates with web-servers.

**Bonus / Update:**

Python (unsurprisingly) has a small WSGI server in the standard library for testing. If you add this in the bottom of your file, you can run it as any old executable for testing purposes, and then let Apache take over for production:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

    httpd = make_server('', 8080, application)
    print "Serving on http://localhost:8080"

    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: I got the following as an error, out of the apache log. As far as I can tell, it thinks it's not getting a string.

Comment: [Sat Mar 05 17:06:14 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=2844): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/file.py'.
[Sat Mar 05 17:06:14 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Mar 05 17:06:14 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/var/www/file.py", line 2, in application
[Sat Mar 05 17:06:14 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     start_response(200, [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
[Sat Mar 05 17:06:14 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] TypeError: expected byte string object for status, value of type int found

Comment: Ah. My bad. I'm used to frameworks doing all the tricky stuff for me ;). I've updated the `200` to `'200 OK'` per http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/

Comment: Great, that works. Last question: how do I make it display in html? My browser shows the return in plaintext, ignoring the markup.

Comment: Wait, got it: change text/plain to text/html.

Comment: On second thought, ONE more question: how do I get arguments from the url?